# How to get Matlab's automatic documentation to display multiple lines for an object

Tags: matlab, documentation

I am updating some Matlab comments and documentation to be more thorough. I am struggling to get an objects documentation to display properly.

If a property or method has a multi-line documentation comment, then only the first line displays for the object's documentation. The full multi-line comment does display for the property or method's help and documentation.

```
class ExampleObject
    function ExampleFcn
        % displays for both: 'doc ExampleObject' and 'doc ExampleObject.ExampleFcn'
        % only displays for 'doc ExampleObject.ExampleFcn'
    end
end
```

Is there a (non-tedious) way to get multiple lines to display for the object's documentation as well?